# Hibernate querying on ghost column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities that used to be linked by a one to many relation but now they are linked by a many to many relation declared as follow :

SalesTeam entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SALES_TEAMS")
public class SalesTeam {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(name = "WORKFLOW_FOR_SALESTEAM", inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "WFC_ID")
    })
    private List<WorkFlowCode> workFlowCodes = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And the WorkFlowCode entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WORK_FLOW_CODE")
public class WorkFlowCode {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(name = "WORKFLOW_FOR_SALESTEAM", inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "ST_ID")
    })
    private List<SalesTeam> salesteam = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

As I said the relation use to be one SalesTeam for several workflow codes but the requirement change and now it need to be a many to many relation. So I had a relation table and remove the former SALES_TEAM_ID column from the WORK_FLOW_CODE table. The problem is that now I always get an error when I try to get the WorkFlowCode from a SalesTeam. It appears that hibernate still adds the removed column to the query thus the relation had changed and nothing is left from the former relation description.

Here is the hibernate generated query :

> select workflowco0_.SALES_TEAMS_ID as SALES_TE3_13_0_, workflowco0_.WFC_ID as WFC_ID4_16_0_, workflowco1_.ID as ID1_17_1_ from WORKFLOW_FOR_SALESTEAM workflowco0_ inner join WORK_FLOW_CODE workflowco1_ on workflowco0_.WFC_ID=workflowco1_.ID where workflowco0_.SALES_TEAMS_ID=?

As you can see the former SALES_TEAM_ID from WORK_FLOW_CODE table is still there.

How can I remove it ?
Thx

Comment: Your mappings are wrong. Define the Join Table on one side and use mappedby on the other. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Bi-directional_Many_to_Many